# Bootstrap Typeahead search result is wrapped in div wrapper

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead

I have a search bar wrapped in a wrapper having background color. The search result is not visible as it is wrapped in the wrapper div. Now i want to somehow show the complete result. Also, i tried z-index but it did not help.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="search_box_container">
    <form>
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
            <input id="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control search_bar" name="search_bar" auto-complete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="search_bar_button"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS FOR WRAPPER:

```
.search_box_container{
padding: 0.5em;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
border-radius: 6px;
border:1px solid #DBDBDB;
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

.search_bar{
height: 2.2em;
font-size: 1.45em;
color: black;
font-family: inherit;
} 

.search_bar_button{
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left:-5px;
border-radius: 4px;
background: url('../img/search_bar_button.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
width: 5.2em;
background-position: 0px -2px;
height: 3.05em;
border: 2px solid #067b19;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Ysx/)

Comment: For these types of questions you should make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ok i just resolved the issue. I was adding overflow:hidden; in search_box_container class.

Here is the fix.

    .search_box_container{
        padding: 0.5em;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border:1px solid #DBDBDB;
        position: relative;
}

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Ysx/2/)